# How can i check which nsmenuitem was clicked?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Basically Im trying to add items to a NSMenu which is a submenu of another menu programatically. The problem i has is how im going to separate them from each other. I dont even need them to Run a method, just which one it is using a tag or something.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. *When* do you need to identify the selected menu item? If you need to populate a menu dynamically, set the delegate of the menu and implement `-menuNeedsUpdate:`. If you need to know which menu item invoked an action method, examine the `sender` argument. You can request its `-tag` (which you can assign when you create the menu item).

Comment: Please detail your question. It is too ambiguous: i.e "how im going to separate them from each other" That could imply each submenu from each submenu or submenu from the parent menu or menuItems from parent menu...